# Android application for Tablet

Tags: android, tablet

I have developed an application that is to be run on android Tablet as well. It is working on android phones perfectly. When I ran it on Tablet, it did not expand on whole screen. It just covered a area equal to a mobile device. I want that it also runs on Tablet and cover the whole screen as running on mobile device. Do I have to create two different designs for each type and at run time before using design, I would have to check it whether it is android phone or table?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following block of code in your manifest file after the `<uses-sdk>`tag:

```
<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

**Note:** Add the `android:xlargeScreens="true"` attribute if and only if your `minSdkVersion` is equal to or more than `9`.

In addition to adding this block of code, follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) link. Also suggest you to go through the following links:

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Although I found some views problems but I will handle them soon.

Comment: You're welcome. Good that the solution worked. If you face another problem, well, SO is always there.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in android manifest

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:maxSdkVersion="11"/>
 <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

in Manifest.xml before  tag.

I hope it may be help you.

Comment: Using `maxSdkversion` isn't a good practice. See the **warning** [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max) for more details. Suggest you to remove it before you start getting down votes.

Comment: Ok Thanks Ghost.. I will take care of this. Thanks for sharing knowledge with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ideally you'll design layouts targeted to tablets. You don't *have* to, but you can. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for details. Your app is running in "screen compatibility mode". See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) for info about *that*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used fixed width and height for any view or layout in your app, to support a fixed resolution of your mobile device.

If you use fill_parent, wrap_content and weight property, such things in your app, the app will fill entire screen of any android device. Once review your code.

**Small example**

Assume device has no rotation. Your device has resolution 320 X 240. you have to fill 3 buttons horizontally, you can put each button width=100 and remaining as margin/padding of layout. If you run same app on device with resolution 640 X 480, some space will come after 3 buttons. If you use width=fill_parent and layout_weight=1 for these 3 buttons and parent's layout_width=fill_parent, on any resolution these 3 buttons will fill the entire width of screen.

I hope it may help you.